# Is there any way to force Haskell code ordering to work like F#?

Tags: haskell, f#

I am currently [learning me a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), so for so good.

I am pretty fluent when it comes to F# and I want to try my hand at pure functional programming.

One of the features I have always liked about F# is that the order of your code matters. You can't call a function that you haven't defined yet. This is useful because it guarantees that earlier code files contain low level functions, and later code contains the bigger picture stuff. It forces a structure that I now consider to be a good thing.

Haskell doesn't seem to care much about code order in the same way. Whilst I can choose to structure my code as such, I am not forced to. So at this early stage of learning Haskell, I would like to know if there is some compiler option that forces this?

Comment: I miss that feature from F# too. To some extent this is sort of works in Haskell as well by the virtue of banned module import cycles. Also, you could break the code into multiple libraries.

Comment: Wouldn't this feature prevent mutually recursive definitions from being possible? Or are you just referring to what order different files are processed in, and not the contents of the files?

Comment: You can't call a function you haven't defined yet in *any* language; it sounds more like F# doesn't allow you to *define* a function that uses as-yet-undefined functions.

Comment: I can't think of any way to enforce that using standard tools. Also note that in the presence of mutual recursion (not so uncommon in Haskell), we need to break the order. Maybe one could write a GHC plugin for enforcing non-recursive definitions to be ordered.

Comment: Mutually recursive functions are handled in f# via syntax features. They need to be declared together. Anyways looks like this question has been answered, thanks all.

Comment: If your modules are small enough then it works this way, since you can't have mutually recursive modules (at least not without a lot of `.hs-boot` headache). It's good design, too -- lower-level things should be encapsulated into neat little abstractions.

Comment: " the order of your code matters. You can't call a function that you haven't defined yet." Horrible, horrible, horrible. Sounds like ALGOL vintage 1960 with its `forward` declarations. (I think early Pascal also did something like that.) I always design my program structure top-down. Been doing that for 40 years since programming school. You can always put a stub for a function you're mentioning but haven't yet nutted out: `f = undefined` (but you do need a signature). OTOH, thanks to the C-H correspondence, once you have the signature, the code pretty much writes itself.

Comment: @AntC just want to point out your response to this idea is similar to the revulsion that an OOP programmer would express towards the idea of immutability. Seems like an unnecessary limitation to the uninitiated, but actually is a useful idea.

Comment: "actually is a useful idea". You can't know that until you're equally experienced in both styles. (My "horrible" is from trying to read code.) All you can say is 'actually is the only way I can write the code'. Top-down style dates back to the 1968 'Structured Programming' collection of papers Dahl, Dijkstra, Hoare, and the experimental language CPL, which was the inspiration for C (via a few others). I guess Kernighan & Ritchie were convinced enough they didn't force definition before use.

Comment: @chepner while I can't think of any right now, I'd bet that there _are_ languages in which you can call a function you haven't defined yet (giving some bogus result). In fact this sounds like the kind of thing JavaScript would do... — Thinking about it, this _could_ actually make sense in a language like Agda, when you've just narrowed down the type so much that the compiler can figure out the correct implementation by itself!

Comment: @AntC I've experienced both styles, and I can attest with all certainty that this feature turns out to be very handy in F#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the only circumstance in which Haskell enforces the order of declarations within a module is when there are Template Haskell splices.  In this case, declarations above a given splice may not reference declarations below.  I think this is an unfortunate limitation of template haskell, not a feature per se.

So I think technically you can have GHC enforce the ordering by turning on Template Haskell and adding empty splices to your code. `$(return [])`.  This is a qualified "no" - it can be done, but I've never seen anyone do it, and it's probably annoying to read & write.